# С помощью какого виджета это делается?

Tags: android

Очень похоже на ListView, но хотелось бы быть увереным. Также не совсем понимаю как сделать такие отступы между каждым товаром.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Советую вам присмотреться к RecyclerView и к ItemDecorator, так же можно и к CardView присмотреться, может даже лучше выглядеть будет)

Comment: Это можно делать и с помошью ListView и ResiclerView да и просто LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Это `RecyclerView` где элементы списка оформлены в виде `CardView`

Comment: Врятли это CardView, т.к. тени нет, скорее обычные кастомные элементы с отступами.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но судя по всему что бы подружить RecyclerView  с бд нужно много телодвижений или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Все достаточно просто, пишите врапер для базы, адаптер для RecyclerView. В адаптер передаете даные полученые из базы, а адаптер формирует записи и тд в RecyclerView.

Comment: @Tany [На гите валяется](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) адаптер рисайклера под `Cursor` - читай под БД. Работает отлично - проверял.